# keypress function rus only with enter key (e.which==13)

Tags: jquery

This is my first post here.
After a few weeks reading and learning here I have a specific question:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) { alert('Key press') }; 
});
```

This runs perfectly; an alert box is shown.

When I try with ESC (code 27) or any other key code, it doesn't run.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the keyCode property, not 'which'

```
if(e.keyCode == 27) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, but still the same.
Using your code with '13' it's running but with '27'(ESC) or '38' UpArrow, NO WAY...
mmm any idea?

Comment: keypress & the escape key don't work nicely. Change `keypress` to `keyup` and you should get the result you're looking for.

Comment: Greats! So simple, so easy.. Thanks!.